# Converting P = NP into an effective equivalence algorithm

Tags: complexity-theory, computability

If P = NP, then is it the case that there exists a total recursive function from the set of polynomial-time nondeterministic Turing machines to the set of polynomial-time deterministic Turing machines such that it sends every nondeterministic machine to an equivalent deterministic machine?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a consequence of the existence of NP-complete problems. (Of course a bit of care is needed to state the result precisely, e.g. the set of polytime (non)deterministic machines is not itelf recursive.)